# Which RFC should I use to bring SHA1 and SHA2 authentication to RTSP 1.0?

Tags: http, md5, rtsp, sha1, rfc

RTSP 1.0's [RFC2326](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2326)  uses [RFC2617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#page-10) for WWW Authentication, which is the same used for HTTP authentication. This 2617 is old and only covers `MD5`. I know that RTSP 2.0 is out but I'm working on 1.0. Lots of IP cameras still implement 1.0 only.

I guess some cameras might use SHA1. SHA2 might be too new, I don't know if they use but it's possible.

Which RFC should I read to bring SHA1 and possibly SHA2 to RTSP 1.0? Should I just use the latest WWW Authentication RFC, if such exists?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, RFC 2326 predates RFC 2617, so pedantically speaking, it used an even older version of HTTP auth.

It *appears* you are interested in "Digest" authentication. The relevant spec for that nowadays is RFC 7616. It's supposed to be backwards-compatible, so I would recommend it as the definitive source.

Just be aware of the changes compared to older specs, which the devices you want to talk to might not implement: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7616#appendix-A

Comment: Thanks. I just readed it entirely and implemented SHA2 using the examples from the RFC and it matches the expected responses. However, there's something new that didn't exist before: charsets for usernames. How do I know if RTSP also supports charsets for usernames? Because this RFC is for HTTP. Should I implement it or not?